# How come my lines aren't matching up?

Tags: javascript, trigonometry, isometric

**EDIT: So apparently, PI is finite in JavaScript (which makes sense). But that leaves me with a major problem. What's the next best way to calculate the angles I need?**

Alright, first, my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/joshlalonde/vtfyj/34/

I'm drawing cubes that open up to a 120 degree angle.
So the coordinates are calculated based on (h)eight and theta (120).

On line 46, I have a for loop that contains a nested for loop used for creating rows/columns.

It's somewhat subtle, but I noticed that the lines aren't matching up exactly. The code for figuring out each cubes position is on line 49. One of the things in the first parameter (my x value) for the origin of the cube is off. Can anyone help figure out what it is?

```
var cube = new Cube(
            origin.x + (j * -w * (Math.PI)) +
            (i * w * (Math.PI))
            , origin.y + j * (h / 2) +
            i * (h / 2) +
            (-k*h), h);
```

Sorry if that's confusing. I,j, and k refer to the variable being incremented by the for loops. So basically, a three dimensional for loop.

I think the problem lies with Math.PI. 
The width isn't the problem, or so I believe. I originally used 3.2 (which I somehow guessed and it seemed to line up pretty good. But I have no clue what the magical number is). I'm guessing it has to do with the angle being converted to Radians, but I don't understand why Math.PI/180 isn't the solution. I tried multiple things. 60 (in degrees) * Math.PI/180 doesn't work. What is it for?

**EDIT: It might just be a JavaScript related math problem. The math is theoretically correct but can't be calculated correctly. I'll accept the imperfection to spare myself from re-writing code in unorthodox manners. I can tell it would take a lot to circumvent using trig math.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found the solution!
It's really simple - I was using degrees instead of radians.

```
function Cube(x, y, h) {
this.x = x
this.y = y
this.h = h;
this.theta = 120*Math.PI/180;

this.getWidth = function () {
    return (this.h * Math.sin(this.theta / 2));
};
this.width = this.getWidth();

this.getCorner = function () {
    return  (this.h / 2);
};
this.corner = this.getCorner();
```

}

So apparently Javascript trig functions use Radians, so that's one problem.
Next fix I made was to the offset of each point in the cube. It doesn't need one! (o.O idk why. But whatever it works. I left the old code just in case I discover why later on).

```
 function draw() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Draw a black canvas

var h = 32;

var width = Math.sin(60*Math.PI/180);
var w = h*width;

var row = 9; // column and row will always be same (to make cube)

var column = row;
var area = row * column;
var height = 1;

row--;
column--;
height--;

var origin = {
    x: canvas.width / 2,
    y: (canvas.height / 2) - (h * column/2) + height*h
};

var offset = Math.sqrt(3)/2;
offset = 1;

for (var i = 0; i <= row; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= column; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k <= height; k++) {

        var cube = new Cube(
            origin.x + (j * -w * offset) +
            (i * w * offset)
            , origin.y + (j * (h / 2) * offset) +
            (i * (h / 2) * offset) +
            (-k*h*offset), h);
            var cubes = {};  
        cubes[i+j+k] = cube; // Store to array

        if (j == column) {
            drawCube(2, cube);
        }

        if (i == row) {
            drawCube(1, cube);
        }

        if (k == height) {
        drawCube(0,cube);
        }

        }
    }
}
```

}

See the full Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/joshlalonde/vtfyj/41/

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems...

1. Change line 35 to `var w=h*Math.sin(30);`.  The `30` here matches the `this.theta / 4` in the `Cube` `getWidth`method since `this.theta` equals 120.
2. Use the following code to generate the position of your new cube.  You don't need `Math.Pi`.  You needed to use both the cube width and height in your calculation.

   ```
   var cube = new Cube(
       origin.x+ -j*w - i*h,
       origin.y + -j*w/2 + i*h/2,
       h);
   ```

Comment: I've tried your suggestions and they didn't quite seem to work. Also, I added in a new factor - the height of the entire cube platform. (Not to be confused with height of a cube).

Updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/joshlalonde/vtfyj/34/

1. Just remembered that the width there is actually half the diagonal. The entire diagonal width (and hence width of cube) is h*sin(60).
2. I did that and it made a weird stair-case looking thing. It was really cool though XD